# C: Why will I get an error on free()

Tags: c, free

I wrote the following function which will break in the lines marked with `// Breakpoint`:

```
char *parseNextWord(char *str)
{
    static char *lastStr = "";
    static int lastPosition = 0;

    if (strcmp(lastStr, str) != 0)
    {
        lastStr = str;
        lastPosition = 0;
    }

    if (lastPosition > 0 && str[lastPosition - 1] == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    char *word = "";
    int wLength = 0;
    while (str[lastPosition] != ' ' && str[lastPosition] != '\n' && str[lastPosition] != '\0')
    {
        char *tmp = (char*)malloc(++wLength * sizeof(char));
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(word); i++)
        {
            tmp[i] = word[i];
        }

        tmp[sizeof(*tmp) - 1] = str[lastPosition];
        free(word); // Breakpoint
        word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(tmp); i++)
        {
            word[i] = tmp[i];
        }

        free(tmp); // Breakpoint
        lastPosition++;
    }

    while (str[lastPosition - 1] != '\0' && (str[lastPosition] == ' ' || str[lastPosition] == '\n' || str[lastPosition] == '\0'))
    {
        lastPosition++;
    }

    return word;
}
```

The function can be called like this:

```
char* string = "Name1 Name2\nName3 Name4\nName1";

int totalCount = 0;

char *nextWord = parseNextWord(string);
while (nextWord != 0)
{
    for (int c = 1; c < argc; c++)
    {
        if (strcmp((const char*)argv[c], nextWord) == 0)
        {
            totalCount++;
        }
    }

    nextWord = parseNextWord(string);
}
```

Why is my code breaking on free? How can I improve it?

Comment: `char *word = "";` - on the first iteration, you are freeing a pointer which wasn't allocated by `malloc()`. You probably meant `char *word = NULL;` instead. By the way, that's a strange way of managing your memory. Why don't you treat `word` just like `tmp` and allocate it at the beginning of the loop body? Then you could just free it along with `tmp` at the end.

Comment: @MarcoAlka       if you need to free the memory - assign it to NULL (i.e. `word(or temp whicheve) = 0`) and then call free(temp) or free(word) whichever - if this is convenient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant code I see is:

```
char* word = "";
free(word);
```

You did not allocate the empty string (`""`), so you cannot free it.

***You can only `free` what you `malloc`***

If you didn't allocate it, don't try to free it.

---

**P.S.** Here is my best list of functions which allocate memory that can be freed:

```
malloc
realloc 
calloc
strdup
asprintf 
vasprintf
(notably: _not_ alloca)
```

Maybe there are others as well?

Comment: Thank you! That would explain the first iteration. I malloc word afterwards, so it should work on the second iteration. What about the second breakpoint?

Comment: OK, the second one is now gone, too... strange, but thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarcoAlka Your code is already broken. No point in trying to figure out what it does.

Comment: @MarcoAlka You are also misusing `sizeof()` – google what it does. It does not yield the dynamic size of the object. Also, you are leaking memory by not freeing `word` in the end of the last iteration. Furthermore, casting the return value of `malloc` (e. g. `(char *)malloc(some_size)`) is pointless and harmful – all it does is decrease readability. You have a lot of very serious misunderstandings about memory management (and C programming in general) – please read an appropriate introductory-level tutorial instead of asking first.

Answer (score 0):

because you didn't allocate word the first time you entered the loop.
you just make it point to "" which is not allocated dynamically.

my suggestion to make it work is to add integer variable before the while with initial value 0  :

```
if (flag != 0) {
free(word);
} else {
word = 1;
}
```